# MUI v412.4 override default icon for component like Select (chevron) or Chip (onDeleteIcon)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I am trying to figure out how to replace the default icon for e.g the Chip component when using onDelete. or even the chevron icon on Select component, across whole project.I have to use MUI v4.12.4 for now. I could override in v5 using Theme.components..as seen below. But how do it in v4 ? I want to override the icon in whole project.

```
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material";
import Icon from '@mui/icons-material/AlarmAddRounded';

MUI V5 version which works
export const myTheme: ThemeOptions = {
  components: {
    MuiChip: {
        defaultProps: {
          deleteIcon: <Icon />,
        }
    }
  },
};

MUI V4 where it does not work
export const myTheme: ThemeOptions = {
  props: {
    MuiChip: {
        deleteIcon: <Icon />,
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic setup correct -- pass that theme object, [with your desired props set](https://v4.mui.com/customization/globals/#default-props), into the `createTheme()` function and then assign the result to your `ThemeProvider`, for example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  props: {
    MuiChip: {
      deleteIcon: <AcUnitIcon />
    },
    MuiSelect: {
      IconComponent: AcUnitIcon
    }
  }
});

...

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Chip
    label="Delete Icon from Theme"
    clickable
    color="primary"
    onDelete={() => console.log("noop")}
      />
   <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={10}
   >
     ...
   </Select>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Which would produce:
[image]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zt35hf?file=/demo.js